# Delete space between numbers

Tags: notepad++

If I have the following numbers:_

```
[   1   ,   2   ,   4   ,   46  ,   59  ,   63  ,   74  ,   97  ,   111 ,   123 ,   143 ,   150 ,   179 ,   197 ,   268 ,   278 ,   287 ,   303 ]
```

I want to delete the space between these numbers

For example:_

```
[1,2,4,46,59,63,74,97,111,123,143,150,197,268,278,287,303]
```

How can do that in notepad++

I have tried to do like Edit → find what `^\s*` → Replace with nothing

Answer (score 4):

The easiest way would be to use normal search and replace, and simply replace a space for nothing.

There's no need to use complicated regex searches in this case.

You can just press the space bar in the upper field, and nothing in the bottom field and press Replace all.

Comment: Agreed. The only way this wouldn't work is if there are other spaces in the document that you want to preserve. Since the asker didn't indicate anythin gof hte sort should be fine.

Comment: Given the what he tried himself, its safe to assume he is trying to replace every space in the document.

Comment: fair point. emoticon to fill the gap.

Answer (score 1):

You tried: `^\s*`, that is: "Any expression that **starts** with zero or more spaces". In your case, that won't match anything since this line starts with the `[` character.

Instead, try using `\s*` as expression. That will remove *any* spaces within your document.